# Django issue contact form with attribute?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

models.py :

```
class InformationRequest(models.Model):
    from_email = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=350)
```

forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from .models import InformationRequest
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
   from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'contact__input', 'placeholder': 'Email'}))
   subject = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'contact__input', 'placeholder': 'Subject'}))
   message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'contact__input', 'cols': 0, 'rows': 8, 'placeholder': 'Message'}), required=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Home, About, Profile, Category, Skills, Portfolio
from .forms import ContactForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect


def index(request):
   # Home
   home = Home.objects.latest('updated')

   # About
   about = About.objects.latest('updated')
   profiles = Profile.objects.filter(about=about)

   # Skills
   categories = Category.objects.all()

   skills = Skills.objects.all()

   # Portfolio
   portfolios = Portfolio.objects.all()

   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ContactForm()
   else:
       form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect('success')

   context = {
       'home': home,
       'about': about,
       'profiles': profiles,
       'categories': categories,
       'portfolios': portfolios,
       'form': form,
       'skills': skills,
   }

   return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

So here is the problem

I would like to keep the attribute on the form.py to the variable?
Why because it then keeps the CSS structure with it.
So do you know how to have the form Post save to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize the form with `request.POST` for a POST request, and without it for a GET request, you did it the other way around, you thus should work with:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('success')
else:
    form = ContactForm()
```

Furthermore your form is a simple form, not a `ModelForm`, so you can not save it. A simple solution is to make it a `ModelForm` with:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
   # ⋮

    class Meta:
        model = InformationRequest
        fields = ['from_email', 'subject', 'message']
```

Comment: I believe that tere is no connection from models and forms .... I have the Attribute error with the submit , Error : 'ContactForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: @JS_account: no, you wrote `if request.method == 'POST"` and then you constructed a `ContactForm()` (so *without* the `request.POST` and `request.FILES`).

Comment: @JS_account: the reason it produced an error was because you used a `Form`, not a `ModelForm`, and a simple form has *no* `.save()` method. see update on how to fix the form.

Comment: I have the following error by changing the form into ModelForm in form.py : from django import forms
from .models import InformationRequest
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'contact__input', 'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'contact__input', 'placeholder': 'Subject'}))
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'contact__input', 'cols': 0, 'rows': 8, 'placeholder': 'Message'}), required=True)

Comment: @JS_account: exactly what is the error?

Comment: Nevermind it works thanks